# Show that for $x\geq 1$ and $c>0$, show that $\dfrac{1}{x}\leq x^{c-1}$

Tags: calculus

[image]

I've done part a, and I presume I'm somehow meant to use it to do part b, but I have no idea how to do it.

for part (a):

$a=1, b=n, f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$

Comment: There is nothing to part b) and it has no connection to a).  The two will get together in c).

Comment: Could you add your work for part $(a)$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas how do I do part b? Am I trying to squeeze it? Also edited my part (a) work into it

Comment: Part b) is equivalent to $1\le x^c$, which is obvious.

Comment: And for c) you can for example pick $c=1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For b), note that for positive $x$, the inequality $\frac{1}{x}\le x^{c-1}$ is equivalent to $1\le x^{c}$. And the latter inequality holds if $x\ge 1$.

For c), by the result of b) and a), we have, taking $c=1/2$,
$$\ln n=\int_1^n \frac{1}{x}\,dx \le \int_1^n x^{-1/2}\,dx=2n^{1/2}-2.$$
Divide by $n$. It follows that for $n\ge 1$ we have 
$$0\le \frac{\ln n}{n} \le\frac{2\sqrt{n}-2}{n}.$$
Now take the limit as $n\to\infty$.